# Set GRUB console-mode resolution

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, display-resolution

I can't figure out how to set the resolution for text-mode GRUB - that is, with the `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` option set in `/etc/default/grub`. When I set a resolution using `GRUB_GFXMODE` or `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD`, I get a "no video mode set" error on boot, and when I try to set resolution using `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vga=xxx"`, I get a message saying that `vga=xxx` is deprecated. I have a 1080p screen, and I can get the framebuffer terminal inside Linux working just fine, but I can't figure out how to set any resolution at all for non-graphical GRUB. I am using the proprietary nVidia drivers, which is the entire reason I am running GRUB in text mode to begin with.

My current GRUB settings:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=640x480x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920x1080x32
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Open terminal, `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Change the resolution you need in `GRUB_GFXMODE=`
3. Add this line right below it >> `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep`
4. Save & Exit
5. Type in terminal: `sudo update-grub`
6. Then finally: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
7. Reboot

Comment: What's the purpose of the last command? Isn't `update-grub` enough? If not, why not?

Comment: The last command consolidate the new resolution to be set by default every time you boot, there is many issues with hybrid graphic cards that obstructs any change on grub ( For instance, Nvidia graphic cards sets grub on the highest possible resolution your hardware can offer)

Comment: This didn't work - I still get the "no video mode" error, but now all my ttys are at a very low resolution (640x480, I assume). This happens regardless of whether the `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD` line is present or not.